# Find specific keyword and count it in Python

Tags: python

I trying to find how many specific keyword in string but the output is not similar with the logic

```
input = raw_input('Enter the statement:') //I love u
keyword = raw_input('Enter the search keyword:') //love

count = 0

for i in input:
    if keyword in i:
        count = count + 1

print count
print len(input.split())
```

Expectation

```
1
3
```

Reality

```
0
3
```

Comment: Hint: if you put `print i` inside your loop, what do you think the output would be? Try it and see if it matches your prediction.

Comment: i got like this one, i
 
l
o
v
e
 
u

Comment: Exactly.  You are iterating through the string: each character, not each word.  Remember how you found the *number* of words?  Do something similar to iterate through each word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input` is a string, so iterating over it will give you each character individually. You probably meant to `split` it:

```
for i in input.split():
```

Note that using a list comprehension may be more elegant than a `for` loop:

```
count = len([x for x in input.split() if x in keyword])
```

Comment: Note that the `keyword in i` and the `x == keyword` methodologies are not the same. Consider the input "firetrucks put out fire" and the keyword "fire", the former returns 2 counts and the latter returns 1.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the line `for i in input`. Here, `input` is a string which is an [iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols) in Python. This means you can do something like:

```
for char in 'string':
    print(char)
# 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'
```

Instead, you can use the [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) method.

```
input.count(keyword)
```

As noted in a comment above, if you have the input "I want an apple" with the keyword "an", `str.count` will find two occurrences. If you only want one occurrence, you will need to split the input and then compare each word for equality.

```
sum(1 for word in input.split() if word == keyword)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn the statement into a list, like this:

```
input = raw_input('Enter the statement:').split()   //I love u
keyword = raw_input('Enter the search keyword:')     //love

count = 0

for i in input:
    if keyword in i:
        count = count + 1

print count
print len(input)
```

This will allow the loop to correctly identify your desired items.